# Ionic 3 multiple small size modals vs one big modal with if conditions

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm supposed to make a profile page similar to linkedIn's profile. Users should add some data -via multiple forms- like work experience, education, etc. I'm currently using ionic 3 framework (with lazyload) for developing the app. I'm hesitated whether to make one modal containing all forms and use *ngIf on all forms to decide what form to show, Or to make multiple modals each containing a form and load each one separately. Which solution would be practical?

Comment: I recommend u to use First option *ngif because this use in your same component while if u create modal u have to define different component associate with it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a third option: A page with 3 slides, each slide containing a different form.

You can have a form in each slide, you can control which slide the user can see, there's no loss in performance, you can validate each form separately and so on.

I don't know how much you know about Ionic, but i'll give a simple example and then say what you'll need to study to achieve this.

yourPage.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide>
      <form [formGroup]="firstForm">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label stacked>Name</ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName="name"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <button ion-button block round (click)="goToNextForm()">Next Form</button>
      </form>
    </ion-slide>
    ... <!-- Your two other slides -->
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

yourPage.ts

```
// You'll need ViewChild to reference the slide component
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
// removed Navcontroller and navParams because on't know if you need them
import { Slides, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
// i don't use formBuilder
import { Validators, FormControll, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-your-page',
  templateUrl: 'yourPage.html'
})
export class YourPage {
  // You'll need this to reference the slides so you can controll them
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  // i'll create just the first form
  public firstForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControll('', Validators.required)
  });
  constructor(){}

  // in this lifecycle hook i'll block the user interaction with the slides
  // so it can't swipe the slides with gestures
  ionViewDidLoad = () => this.slides.lockSwipes(true);

  // if the form is valid i'll send the user to the next form
  goToNextForm = () => {
    if(this.firstForm.valid) {
      // save your form data or do whatever you need to do with the user input
      // then unblock the swipes, swipe to the next form and block the swipe again
      this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
      this.slides.slideNext();
      this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
    } else {
      // the form is invalid, do what you need to do
    }
  }
}
```

You can also have navigation buttons in the slides if the user can go forth and back in the slides, if there's no obligation to complete one to go to another.

To achieve this you'll need to know:

- How to work with Slides (check ionic slides docs).
- How to work with the ViewChild, but this is not important because the only think you'll ViewChild for is to create a reference for the slides, but it's nice to learn.
- How to work with forms in angular, beeing it the way i've done or using FormBuilder.

If you don't like this idea and still wants to stick to your two options i recommend using the ngIf option, but instead of the ngIf try using the ngSwitch.

Using multiple modals can lend you more work to do since in the page that's presenting the forms you'll need to validate each modal form, save the user input data somewhere and retrieve it when you're going to save. Or you'll presente modal over modal, which can be a little tricky to controll and also'll have all the work i've mentioned above.

Hope this helps.